# How to check Regular Expression for Timestamp in GWT?

Tags: java, regex, gwt

What will be the regular expression for following Timestamp format

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S

YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S AM/PM

YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S AM/PM Z

YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S Z
```

Where

```
Y: year, 
M: Month,
D: Date,
H: hour,
m: minute,
s: second,
S: Milisecond 3 digit only,
Z: Time zone.
```

I am getting timestamp format in string format so want to validate it.

How to check above regular expression in GWT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just something simple as only describing the pattern like this:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}(?: [AP]M)?(?: [+-]\d{4})?$
```

as any tentative of real date validation with a regex sounds inherently wrong.

I got the uppercase Z as RFC822 timezone, regex needs changes to comply to TZDs or general textual time zones.

Comment: ^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}(?: [AP]M)?(?: [+-]\\d{4})?$ right ?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `Datejs` which relays on js to check a date-string, Gwt comes with [DateTimeFormat](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) to parse date-string and format dates with support for locales. It raises a `IllegalArgumentException` in the case the parsed string doesn't match the expected format .

```
String dateStr = "2011-04-21 20:37:36.999 -0800";
String fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S Z"; // your 4th case: YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S Z
DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(fmt);
try {
  Date date = format.parse(dateStr);
  System.out.println("Validated: " + date);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  System.out.println("Validation error: " + e.getMessage());
}

dateStr = "2011-04-21 08:37:36.999 PM -0800"; // your 3rd case YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S AM/PM Z
fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S a Z";
format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(fmt);
try {
  Date date = format.parse(dateStr);
  System.out.println("Validated: " + date);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  System.out.println("Validation error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

You dont say whether the format string is fixed or it can be provided in runtime before performing the validation. So in the second case you need to use `replace` to change 'Y' by 'y', and 'AM/PM' to 'a' which are the symbols used in `DateTimeFormat`

Answer (score 0):

I would say use [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

Otherwise you will need to do a lot of coding, and regex is not the best for verifying timestamps and if it is valid.
Datejs will check the date validity, and from that you will receive a Date object or null (if it is invalid!).

> Date.parse("2013-02-02 12:01:01.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.u");

**For more information see:**

> Datejs [API documentation](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation)
>
> Datejs [Format spec](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers)