# Verifying format of 'date'/'timestamp'/'timestamp with time' zone type parameter in oracle script

Tags: oracle, validation, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I need to verify the format of input parameter of '`timestamp with time zone`' type. It is passed as substitution variable in the script.
The format is `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM'`.
How should I verify that the passed value is given format. Which oracle function to use for this?

I **cannot** use **to_timestamp_tz** function as it will convert just char-exp into timestamp with tz.
Here I want to validate the format of passed '`timestamp with time zone`' variable.

Comment: Dates do not have any format. They are stored in an internal format which is Oracle proprietary. in a What you see is for display in human format. All you need is use a proper format model to ensure the explicit conversion happens.

Comment: You need a REGULAR EXPRESSION to validate a TIMESTAMP.  This question is a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057716/regular-expression-to-validate-a-timestamp

Comment: Moreover, possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662597/how-to-check-regular-expression-for-timestamp-in-gwt

Comment: It would be the worst idea to validate timestamps with regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` for ex:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('1999-12-01 11:00:00 -8:00',
   'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ converts char/varchar/varachar2 into timestamp with tz. I want to verify the format of timestamp with tz type